# Python Class creation to attach mathematical model and play with variables

Tags: python, class, data-science, backend, pyomo

I am trying to create a software with interface, but first I need to create the backend. As pyomo or other library can construct models,
I want to do it in my class. So the main idea is to first 1): create the object; 2):declare my variables and parameters within the object;
3): add ordinary differential equations to my object; 4) add optional equations to my object.

As pyomo, for example, to add an equation you can use a method for example, called Constraint, where it works as follows, e.g.: `model.C1 = Constraint(expr = (a*x**2 == 3))`.
Also in pyomo for you to create a parameter and put into the model you use for example: `model.P = Param(initialize=value)`. A variable is created as `model.variable = Var(bounds=(0, None))`.

I just need to understand these basic things, I mean, how to create methods in a class to do the same. Just these basic. To clarify what I want to do, here is a
reverse engineering, my main script is:

```
model = my_class()

#DECLARING PARAMETERS

model.parameter(P1)
model.parameter(P2)
model.parameter(P3)
model.parameter(P4)
model.parameter(P5)

#DECLARING VARIABLES

model.variable(X[0])  # declaring X and W as variables, obs.: the argument is an object to the class and other methods inside this class?

model.variable(X[1])  

model.variable(W[0])  

model.variable(W[1])  

#PROCESS MODEL CONSTRUCTION:

#use model.ODE to add an ODE to the model

model.ODE( expr= (  Y[0] ==  P1*X[0] - P2*X[1] + P3*W[1] )    ) # Y[0] is related as being the derivative

model.ODE( expr= ( Y[1] ==  P4*W[1] - P5*X[0] )    ) # Y[1] is related as being the derivative 

model.solve() # << ignore this line, since I still will create the method
```

THE MOST important thing is that "expr" must be an argument for other future method creations inside the class! So the python must recognize it as being an argument
output as well, so I can insert them into other methods. Once the user declare these expressions I can play with other methods...

Comment: You could send the parameters and variables into the `__init__` method. Maybe sketch out the using code (even better, as a unit test) and then fill in the class method(s) - maybe you just need the `__init__` and `solve`?

Comment: I need to construct a model with a class and inside it I will take all the input parameters in the main script and put them as an argument to other methods inside the same object. Finally, I will create the solve method. But to do so, I need first to create the model, but my the hard question that I am having now is how to do a class that recognize objects as inputs even if I don't declare them before in the main script. Do you have any idea how to do it? Or even better, could you please have either a shareable reference or code on how to create a class to attach mathematical model? Thanks!